# Filter a list of images by similarity relationship

Tags: python, numpy, igraph, graph-theory, independent-set

I have a list of images names and a (thresholded) similarity matrix for them. The similarity relationship is reflexive and symmetric but not necessary transitive, i.e. if `image_i` is similar to `image_j` and to `image_k`, then it doesn't necessary mean that `image_j` and `image_k` are similar.

For example:

```
images = ['image_0', 'image_1', 'image_2', 'image_3', 'image_4']

sm = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
               [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
               [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
               [1, 1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

The similarity matrix `sm` is interpreted as follows: if `sm[i, j] == 1` then `image_i` and `image_j` are similar, otherwise they are not similar. Here we see that `image_0` is similar to `image_1` and `image_2`, but `image_1` and `image_2` are not similar (this is just one example of non-transitivity).

I want to keep the maximum number of unique images (that are all pairwise non-similar according to the given `sm` matrix). For this example it would be `[image_2, image_3, image_4]` or `[image_1, image_2, image_3]` (in general there are multiple such subsets but I don't mind which to keep as long as they are of maximum length). I am looking for an efficient way to do this since I have thousands of images.

**Edit**: My original solution was the following

```
np.array(images)[np.tril(sm).sum(0) == 1]
```

However it's not guaranteed that it will return a **maximun length subset**. Consider the following example:

```
sm = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
               [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
               [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
               [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

This solution will return `['image_1', 'image_4']`, whereas the desired result is `['image_0', 'image_2', 'image_4']` or `['image_1', 'image_2', 'image_4']`.

**Update**: Please see my answer which explains the problem in more detail using graph theory. I am still open to suggestions since I haven't found a reasonably fast way to achieve the result for a list of thousands of images.

Comment: why in your example are you not "keeping" image_0?

Comment: @Gulzar, because image_0 is similar to image_2.

Comment: but it is different than image 3, and similarity is not transitive.
I would prefer if you gave a more detailed explanation of the requirements.

Comment: @Gulzar Since image_0 is similar to image_2, I don't need them both in the final list. Imagine that they are exact duplicates, so there is no reason to keep them both, even though image_0 is not similar to image_3.

Comment: Initially, you only have one unique image #3. But after removing image #0 from the list, image #2 also becomes unique. Thus, deleting images, we can get a list in which all the remaining images will be unique right?

Comment: If so, then the answers in your problem: [0,3], [1,2,3], [2,3,4] and all subsets, such as [1,2], [1,3], [ 2,3], [2,4], [3,4]. Do you need all of them or just one? What are the criteria for choosing the most preferred result?

Comment: @Sergey The final list will have all the possible images that are pairwise non-similar. So in the example the result is [1,2,3] or [2,3,4]. Which one I don't care, e.g. the one with the first images.

Comment: similarity is by definition transitive. If you define something else, you have to make it clear. I am voting to close this.

Comment: for me the question is clear; there must have been some threshold that said if two images were similar

Comment: @marke, yes exactly, there is a threshold for the similarity. I didn't provide details on that (the metric and threshold I use for similarity) because the similarity matrix is provided directly.

Comment: @AndreasK. The [0,3] is also the result. Why did you drop them? Is it because of its length? If so it is an additional criteria. You need the set of maximum size.

Comment: @Sergey yes the set of maximum size (to keep all the possible images with that criterion).

Comment: @AndreasK. It will be a lot of code with recursion, checks and creation of copies of lists. I offer simple code where only one option is selected every time. Unfortunately, I am not ready to mathematically prove that the solution will be the best. But the cycle will not be infinite, since at each step exactly one (worst) element is deleted.

Comment: What's wrong with my solution? Is it too slow, or am I missing something?

Comment: @marke I haven't yet tested any of the solutions  because I am away from my computer. It seems correct, but the speed might be the issue. Will test later

Comment: @marke Try to change the order of images and check your solution again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After researching it a little bit more, I found that this is the so called **maximum independent set problem** in graph theory, which is unfortunately NP-hard.

An [independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) S of a graph G is a subset of vertices of G, such that no vertices in S are adjacent to one another. In our case, we are looking to find a maximum independent set (MIS), i.e. an independent set with the largest possible number of vertices.

There are a couple of libraries for working with graphs and networks, such as *igraph* or *NetworkX*, which have functions for finding maximum independent sets. I ended up using igraph.

For my problem, we can think of the images as vertices of a graph G and the "similarity matrix" as the adjacency matrix:

```
images = ['image_0', 'image_1', 'image_2', 'image_3', 'image_4']

sm = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
               [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
               [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
               [1, 1, 0, 0, 1]])

# Adjacency matrix
adj = sm.copy()
np.fill_diagonal(adj, 0)

# Create the graph
import igraph
g = igraph.Graph.Adjacency(adj.tolist(), mode='UNDIRECTED')
```

---

[image]

---

```
# Find the maximum independent sets
g.largest_independent_vertex_sets()
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)]
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Unfortunately this is too slow for thousands of images (vertices). So I am still open to suggestions for a faster way to do it (perhaps instead of finding all the MIS, just find one).

**Note**: the proposed solutions by @Sergey (UPDATE#1) and @marke don't always return a MIS -- they are greedy *approximate* algorithms which delete a
vertex of maximum degree until no edge remains. To demonstrate this, consider the following example:

```
sm = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
               [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
               [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
               [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Both solutions return `[3, 5]`, but for this example the maximum independent sets are two, `[(0, 3, 4), (1, 2, 5)]`, as are correctly found by `igraph`. To see why these solutions fail to find the MIS, below is a gif that shows how the vertices and edges are removed at each iteration (which is the "side effect" of `np.argmax` returning the first occurrence for multiple occurrences of the maximum value):

[image]

The Sergey's solution (UPDATE#2) seems to work, however it is much much slower than the igraph's `largest_independent_vertex_sets()`. For speed comparison you can use the following randomly generated similarity matrix of length 100:

```
a = np.random.randint(2, size=(100, 100))

# create a symmetric similarity matrix
sm = np.tril(a) + np.tril(a, -1).T  
np.fill_diagonal(sm, 1)  

# create adjacency matrix for igraph
adj = sm.copy()
np.fill_diagonal(adj, 0)
```

**Update**: it turns out that although I have thousands of images - vertices, the number of edges is relatively small (i.e. I have a sparse graph), so using igraph to find MIS is acceptable it terms of speed.
Alternatively, as a compromise, one could use a greedy approximate algorithm for finding a large independent set (or a MIS if lucky enough). Below is an algorithm which seems pretty fast:

```
def independent_set(adj):
    ''' 
    Given adjacency matrix, returns an independent set
    of size >= np.sum(1/(1 + adj.sum(0)))
    '''
    adj = np.array(adj, dtype=bool).astype(np.uint8)
    np.fill_diagonal(adj, 1)  # for the purposes of algorithm

    indep_set = set(range(len(adj)))
    # Loop until no edges remain
    while adj.sum(0).max() > 1: 
        degrees = adj.sum(0)
        # Randomly pick a vertex v of max degree
        v = random.choice(np.where(degrees == degrees.max())[0])
        # "Remove" the vertex v and the edges to its neigbours
        adj[v, :], adj[:, v] = 0, 0      
        # Update the maximal independent set
        indep_set.difference_update({v})
    return indep_set
```

Or even better, we can get a *maximal* independent set:

```
def maximal_independent_set(adj):  
    adj = np.array(adj, dtype=bool).astype(np.uint8)
    degrees = adj.sum(0)
    V = set(range(len(adj)))  # vertices of the graph
    mis = set()  # maximal independent set
    while V:
        # Randomly pick a vertex of min degree
        v = random.choice(np.where(degrees == degrees.min())[0])
        # Add it to the mis and remove it and its neighbours from V
        mis.add(v)
        Nv_c = set(np.nonzero(adj[v])[0]).union({v})  # closed neighbourhood of v
        V.difference_update(Nv_c)
        degrees[list(Nv_c)] = len(adj) + 1
    return mis
```

Comment: My congratulations!!! You found mathematical solution and you found Python module. It's really cool.

Python is not the best tool for solving NP-hard problems. Python modules mostly use C-code to speed up execution. If you find module that uses GPU for this task it will be much faster.

For example video encoding with ffmpeg runs approximately 12 times faster on my computer when using GPU.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, unique images are those that are not like any others. If this is the case, then we can summarize the rows (or columns) and select those elements of the result that are equal to 1. Then we need to take the same elements from the list of images.

At the moment I don’t know how to remove the cycle at the second step.

```
[images[i] for i in np.where(sm.sum(0) == 1)[0]]
```

**UPDATE#1**

The discussion above leads to a new understanding of the problem.

A new idea is to delete images one at a time, choosing those that have the maximum number of similar ones.

```
images = ['image_0', 'image_1', 'image_2', 'image_3', 'image_4']

sm = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
               [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
               [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
               [1, 1, 0, 0, 1]])

ix = list(range(len(images)))

while sm[ix].T[ix].sum() != len(ix): # exit if we got the identity matrix
  va = sm[ix].T[ix].sum(0)           # count similar images
  jx = np.argmax(va)                 # get the index of the worst image
  del ix[jx]                         # delete index of the worst image

print([images[i] for i in ix])
```

Output:

```
['image_2', 'image_3', 'image_4']
```

**UPDATE#2**

The same but with check of every branch with the worst value of similarity

```
res = []

def get_wres(sm, ix):
  if sm[ix].T[ix].sum() == len(ix):
    res.append(list(ix))
    return
  va = sm[ix].T[ix].sum(0) # count similar images
  vx = np.max(va)          # get the value of the worst
  for i in range(len(ix)): # check every image
    if va[i] == vx:        # for the worst value
      ixn = list(ix)       # isolate one worst
      del ixn[i]           # image and
      get_wres(sm, ixn)    # try without it

get_wres(sm, ix)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Sergey thank you for your answer! However it turns out that your updated solution is too slow for my purposes (see my answer).

Comment: @AndreasK. Thanks for information. I have commented your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**final edit:**
This solution is wrong, see poster's answer. I am leaving this post because it was mentioned couple of times.

Here is with a foor loop, not sure how to get it done without one:

```
results = [images[i] for i in range(len(images)) if sum(sm[i][i:]) == 1]
```

**edit:**

Here is a corrected solution, it's does essentially the same thing that @Sergey's solution but in a different way

```
def put_zeros_to_image_with_most_similarities(arr: np.array):
    index = np.sum(arr, axis=1).argmax()
    if np.sum(arr[index], axis=0) == 1:
        return
    arr[index] = 0
    arr[:, index] = 0
for _ in sm:
    put_zeros_to_image_with_most_similarities(sm)
results = [images[i] for i in range(len(images)) if sum(sm[i][i:]) == 1]
```

Comment: As pointed out by @Sergey, if you swap e.g. `image_0` with `image_4`, the result using your solution will be `[image_0, image_3]`, but we still should get the maximum length subset, i.e. `[image_2, image_3, image_4]` or `[image_1, image_2, image_3]`.

Comment: yeah, I updated the answer to be correct (I hope, it's quite tricky to think of all special cases and possibilites)

Comment: I am afraid this is not the correct solution, see my answer. Thanks anyway!